# How can I store variable whose values are changing in a json format in Karate Framework?

Tags: karate

I have one feature file from where I am getting three results and I need these three results in a json format so that I can use it.

I have stored the three results in three variables `query1`, `query2` and `query3`.
I tried below -

- `def request= {id1:&query1,id2:& query2,id3:&query3}`
  But it is not storing the values but showing as it is. Is there any other way I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Solution -

```
* def query1 = 'Karate as API Solution'
* def query2 = 'Karate as Performance Solution'
* def query3 = 'Karate as UI Solution'




  * def fun =
    """
    function()
    {
    var jsonRequest = {}
    jsonRequest.id1 = query1
    jsonRequest.id2 = query2
    jsonRequest.id3 = query3
    return jsonRequest
    }
    """
* def jsonRequest = fun()
* print "Request is ", jsonRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

'request' is a reserved name so do not use the term request.

Below should work.

```
* def query1 = 'Karate as API Solution'
* def query2 = 'Karate as Performance Solution'
* def query3 = 'Karate as UI Solution'


* def jsonRequest =
  """
  {
  id1: '#(query1)',
  id2: '#(query2)',
  id3: '#(query3)',
  }
  """


* print "Request is ", jsonRequest
```